# Automate Photoshop with C#

Tags: c#, photoshop

Looking for a way to add a background layer to existing photoshop files with c# code?

Any ideas?

Thanks
-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Photoshop has a COM interface and here is a document on how to access it via C#.

The specifics of what you want to do will require a bit more digging into Photoshops actual documentation, but [this will get you started.](http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/)

For greater details, check out Adobes [scripting guide and SDK information](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/).

Comment: Link is dead - archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20160307002717/http://www.pcpix.com/pcpix/Photoshop/

Answer (score -3):

You should not have a problem today if you still searching a way to automate Photoshop:

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html

Comment: Sorry for that joke obviously this post was asked 11 years ago, but you have today better options to automate tasks in Photoshop.